# Need help to convert the 32 bit integer r to charcters

Tags: c++

```
#define ISO6391(a,b) ((((b) & 0xff) << 8) | ((a) & 0xff))

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int c = ISO6391('a','b');
    std::cout<<"c= "<<c<<std::endl;
}
```

I have the above code snippet (written by a vendor) to copy a ISO639-1 language code (2 character) to a 32 bit integer. Now I want to extract the code (from 32 bit integer to character/string). Please help. No clue how to do this!

Comment: That’s a 16 bit integer, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the reverse of the above macro

```
char first = c&0xFF;
char second = (c >> 8)&0xFF;
```

You might want to lookup *bitwise operators*.